# How should I store my custom classes?

Tags: c#, .net, class-library

I've gotten to the point where I have made a few classes that I have found to be rather useful for a variety of different projects, they're either extensions of the already existing .Net ones or something entirely new.

Although I may not use them for EVERY project I would most certainly use them again at some point, my questions is what is the best way to keep these stored?

I was thinking about compiling them into a .dll that I can simply reference if necessary but at the moment there are only about 4 different classes, I've always thought that a .dll is more suited towards a larger amount of classes.

Would it just be simpler to store them somewhere in the cloud so I can access them from pretty much any computer?

What has worked best for you?

**Edit:** I'll be using more than one computer as I sometimes use the university computer facilities.

The classes range from memory management helper classes in XNA to niche functions in regular .Net/C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are these classes in any way related? If you want to use one of them, do you need the others? If not, then those don't belong in a common package together.

Robert C. Martin provides some decent introduction in the chapter "Principles of Package and Component Design" of his book "Agile Software Development". There is also a C# adapted version with very similar content called "Agile Principles, Patterns and Practices in C#".

What I'm just saying is, packaging components is not only about thinking components X and Y are "cool enough" to be reused, but also about how you organize things and how well libraries or packages fit into the big picture.

Comment: I understand about the organisational sides of things, I'll more than likely have multiple ways to solve a given solution or multiple classes for a particular framework (XNA). Would it be wise to perhaps compile different .dll's for the different uses they have? Such as one for my XNA work and one for my other C# projects?

Answer (score 2):

If the classes don't fit together naturally as an assembly, keep the source files somewhere like [Github](https://github.com/) and include them in your projects where needed. You can always rearrange them into components at a later date, when you feel it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You could compile them as a DLL and [install them to the GAC](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815808). Then you can reference the DLLs from any project you need, just like any native C# library.

And I agree with Jim Brissom. Compile only the classes that go together as one assembly.

Comment: I get the impression that this is only suitable for one computer, or am I reading it wrong? I'll be using different computers as I am at university.

Comment: I really wouldn't put anything in the GAC unless you love versioning nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

I keep my common classes in sourcegear and then share them into any projects as required.